# xbindkeys loses bindings

Tags: linux, spotify, xbindkeys

I've mapped some of my keyboard function keys (prev/next/play) using xbindkeys. On key press, it just call a dbus command to control Spotify. 
Everything works fine, except it often "forgets" bindings. After some minutes or sometimes hours, I have to run xbindkeys again, or it won't call my script. I even tried to put an xbindkeys call in cron every 5 minutes, and the same call on my .bashrc, but it doesn't work that well. I've noticed most of the time, "play" binding still works while the two others have been forgotten.

So, what am I doing wrong ?